# No syntax errors but php email form continues to fail

Tags: php, html, forms

hopefully you can help, as I am currently stumped.

I have some code implemented in 2 places on my website.

For some reason the form fails to send every time. Below is the code, I have run it through a syntax checker and it's fine as far as that's concerned.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Roofing Solutions Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'info@allroofingsolutions.com'; 
    $subject = 'Question Sent From Website Form';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Number: $number\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
        echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
    }
?>
```

So I am baffled by it. and just for safetys sake, here is the html form:

```
<form method="post" action="contactform.php">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Contact Number</label>
    <input name="number" placeholder="Type Here">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

    <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `$from` looks scary.

Comment: -1 for duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828423/php-form-doesnt-work?rq=1

Comment: your from should be in your header. See example 2 on this page : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thank you Pierre. I'm glad people like you are on this site. Sadly there are too many Fabiens around here to make me even remotely like this place. This is always a last port of call.

Answer (score 0):

```
add header part..
/ To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're doing with body and message, this looks strange for me. Form should be in header, 
A most regular solution :
Your php part :

```
$to = 'info@allroofingsolutions.com'; 
$subject = 'Question Sent From Website Form';
$message = "E-Mail: ".$_POST['email']."\n<br />Number: ".$_POST['number']."\n<hr />Message:\n ".$_POST['message'];
$headers = "From: Roofing Solutions Contact Form <".$to.">\r\n" ;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" ;

if ($_POST['submit'] && _POST['human'] == '4') {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    } 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && _POST['human'] != '4') {
    echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
```